# Open sets in identification topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm reading about identification space and I think I misunderstood some point in the excerpt below.

[image]

The part in red says that the image of the open half-disc of $R$ under $\pi$ is not open in $M$, but I can't see why (or at least why the following reasoning doesn't hold). Since $R \subset \mathbb{E}^2$, I assume the half-disc is open in the subspace topology, and it is the intersection of $R$ with an open set of $\mathbb{E}^2$? Then isn't it the case that the image of this open half-disc has as pre-image an open set of $R$, and then by the definition of the identification topology, that image should be open?

On a side note, if we see $M$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^3$, then can the image of the open half-disc be seen as the intersection of $M$ with an open ball in $\mathbb{E}^3$, and hence open? Is this correct and relevant to our discussion, or am I talking about a whole different topology?

Apologize if this seems trivial. I just want to root out all the misunderstanding that I have.

Comment: Come to think of it, "open half-disk" is a misnomer. The correct term would be "half of an open disk", and that's quite a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the following sentence:

> Then isn't it the case that the image of this open half-disc has as pre-image an open set of R, and then by the definition of the identification topology, that image should be open?

Because the pre-image of the image of the half-disc is **not** the half-disc, since $\pi$ is not injective. It's the half disc plus a bit of the boundary line on the other side of $R$. And that set is not open in $R$.

Comment: Beware, the "half disc" is open in the induced topology on $R$ because it is the intersection of an open disc of $\mathbb{E}^2$ with $R$.

Comment: Right, but the boundary line is not. Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: Well yes, but that's not the point. The point is that $\pi$ isn't an open maping since the image of an open set of $R$ isn't open.

Comment: But if OP's sentence "Then isn't it the case that the image of this open half-disc has as pre-image an open set of R" had been true, then $\pi$ would have been an open mapping. I'm saying why it's not true.

Comment: Oh, I missed the point here... The argument is that the image of the half-disc $H$ isn't open since $\pi^{-1}(\pi(H))$ isn't open.  Well done, that argument is better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

While the half-disc $D$ is open in $R$, its image $\pi(D)$ is not open in $M$. To see why, consider any small neighborhood $V$ of $\mathbf{p}$ . $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is the disjoint union of a neighborhood of $(0,y)$ and a neighborhood of $(3,1-y)$, hence $V$ cannot be contained in $\pi(D)$.

Comment: But in the subspace topology of $R \subset \mathbb{E}^2$, isn't the union of a neighborhood of $(0,y)$ and a neighborhood of $(3, 1 -y)$ open?

Comment: @ensbana yes it is, but its **image** under $\pi$ isn't.

Comment: @ensbana I hope my last edit makes my argument clearer.

Comment: I can see why your argument work, but not why mine doesn't. What's wrong with ascertain whether $\pi(D)$ is open via seeing whether $\pi^{-1}(\pi(D))$ is open or not?

Comment: @ensbana There's nothing wrong with your approach. You just have the wrong pre-image of $\pi(D)$

Comment: I think I got it now!